# Has God created anything since he rested on the 7th day?

Tags: history, creation

Genesis 2 indicates that on the 7th day after creation God rested.

> **[Genesis 2:1-3 NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202:1-3&version=NIV)**
>
> 1 Thus the heavens and the earth were completed in all their vast
>   array.
>
> 2 By the seventh day God had finished the work he had been doing; so
>   on the seventh day he rested from all his work. 3 Then God blessed the
>   seventh day and made it holy, because on it he rested from all the
>   work of creating that he had done.

Is there any indication that he has created anything since then?  Will he create again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. This fits somewhere between an opinionated debate on the meaning of "create" and a verse search question.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, He will create a New Heaven and a New Earth. He will recreate **everything**!

> [Revelation 21:1-5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation%2021:1-5&version=NIV1984) *emphasis mine*
>
> Then I saw a **new heaven** and a **new earth**, for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea. I saw the Holy City, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride beautifully dressed for her husband. And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying, “Now the dwelling of God is with men, and he will live with them. They will be his people, and God himself will be with them and be their God. He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed away.”
>
> He who was seated on the throne said, “I am making **everything new**!” Then he said, “Write this down, for these words are trustworthy and true.”

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about the second part of my question.  Thanks!

Comment: How did I forget about that?

Answer (score 13):

There are instances where God created a few things, but nothing like the original creation.

He created the languages at the Tower of Babel.  He created the manna in the desert, along with the cloud by day and the pillar of fire by night.  He created food for 5,000+ from a small lunch.

Answer (score 6):

There is the theological opinion, that human soul is created by God from nothing every time when new man appears. The first time this view was [expressed by Saint Irenaeus](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irenaean_theodicy). So, the answer to your question might be yes.

Answer (score 5):

This depends a lot on your interpretation of "create," as well as "day."

As my [answer to another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/why-did-god-rest-on-the-7th-day/2301#2301) explains, some believe the seventh day has not yet ended. If you take this view, the answer to your question might be "no, God has not created anything since the seventh day, because nothing has happened since the seventh day."  I think that probably misses the real point of your question, though... I think you're really asking, did creation end after the sixth day.

If you hold to the views of most [old earth creationist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/what-is-old-earth-creationism), the substance of the universe was created instantaneously at the event of the [Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang).  Since then, God has created various life forms, humans being the last one mentioned on the sixth creation "day."

Clearly God has caused certain things (both physical, and non-physical things) to come into existence after the end of the sixth day.  Many people have been born, new rivers have formed, the Church was created (a non-physical thing), etc.  It's even possible/likely that micro-evolution has occurred (although there is debate whether the result can be considered new species or not).  Would you consider that to be "creation?"

The view I would hold is that after the 6th day, God ceased to create new species of plants and animals.

However, this is hard to prove scientifically, because not enough time has passed since the end of the 6th day (possibly as much as 10,000 years, depending on your estimates).  And according to geologists, the fossil record goes back hundreds of millions of years.  There simply aren't enough data points in the last 10,000 years to prove that life isn't continuing to be "created."

So in a nutshell... without further clarification in your question, I think the answer is "It's impossible to say."

Comment: There have been scientifically observed instances of speciation (http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/faq-speciation.html gives one discussion) whether or not the church recognizes them.

Comment: @AdamRedwine: Right, I realize there have been claims along those lines--but many try to refute them. My purpose here is not to weigh in on either side of that debate.

Comment: @AdamRedwine For a minute there I thought you said "There have been scientifically observed instances of ***speculation***"! I laughed and thought, "Isn't that the truth!"

Answer (score 1):

God created man.  As it turns out, babies are created every single day.

So yeah, I'd say God is still creating things.

Comment: lol... sarcastic, but worth considering. +1

Comment: @Jas3.1 It does kind of sound sarcastic, I guess. :)  My opinion is that because of this, we're actually still in the "sixth day" of Creation.  Man is still being created, thus His labor hasn't yet finished.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud teaches that the act of creation is ongoing and is continued through the actions of God's creatures. Unlike the Christian OT, Talmud reads "When God began the creation ... " When God rested, man took over the management of God's world. God inspires individuals to create things, processes, art, and to create a better World, according to God's plan. Human beings are the hands and eyes of God, doing things that God dreams of. He is the architect, and we are the builders. In Talmud, Torah is the blueprint for the creation (the tree of life, in gan eden), and Torah is the blueprint that is re-examined anew with every generation to create things necessary.

[An Anglican]

Answer (score 0):

No, everyone and everything that was created, was created in the first 6 days of creation.

Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host of *them*.

all the host of the heavens (angels)
all the host of the earth (man's)

thats right we were created outside of time and placed in time at our proper time.
we were created and forknew by God and we are eternal -- thats why death never ends for the lost.

> According as he hath chosen us in him before the foundation of the world, that we should be holy and without blame before him in love:  Ephesians 1:4 (KJV)

Comment: Please don't include links that are not relevant to the question your answering. If you'd like to promote your minstry your welcome to include a link in your profile. Or link to it when it is relevant to the question your answering. We do not support signatures here in any form.

Comment: Can you support your assertion that everything was created in the first six days with Scripture references?  I'm sure you can, but if they are not listed, this appears to be just an opinion.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When you get time, please read our [about] and [faq] pages to come up to speed on what makes a good answer, tips for formatting, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Man was (and is) created on the 6th day.  God rested from all of his work on the 7th day.  We look forward to a Sabbath rest with him while we live in this 6th day.

Let me clarify.  For those of us "in time" we are created on the 6th day, (the day of man and modern animals).  The conservative doctrines of providence and continuous creation show that God is still at work (John 5:17) "My father has been working up until now and I work."

Thus, God is still at work (in one sense) and at rest (in another) since God is not limited by time.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: Please update this answer to include information about who believes this, and how common of an interpretation it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is one perspective of the *two* creation stories in Genesis that has everything made by the end of day six, *except* the woman and a few animals.

There is a somewhat common view that Eve was created after the seventh day rest. There are seemingly two creation stories in Genesis. Chapter 1 is the one we are all familiar with and the YEC's often quote it and love it dearly. But many of us often forget to consider that chapter 2 seems to be a different creation story with different details. One way that believers of an inerrant Bible reconciling the two stories is by saying that both are equally true and do indeed detail different events. Chapter 1 begins at the beginning of everything and ends on the seventh day. Chapter 2 briefly recaps that week then begins on some day after the seventh day.

If this view is taken, then God created at least one of every animal in existence out of mud and breathed life into it, just as He did in the first Creation Week, and *also* created Eve from Adam's rib, all *after* the seventh day. Though by scale, this second creation is less involved than the first, lacking in any further creation of actual Earth, celestial bodies, and any plant life.

- [See this answer for the support of the belief that Eve was created after the seventh day.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30689/3961)
- Related: [Support for the opposite opinion that Eve was created on the sixth day.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/30685/3961)

Other items of creation have been hinted on in other answers, and include human souls at conception, food for 5000 from a single basket, and some of the Old Testament manna and pillar of fire kind of things. These are small in comparison to the total creation in Genesis one of all that is, however, Revelation promises an entirely *new* heaven and Earth, which certainly is on the same scale as the first Creation Week.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus the heavens and **the earth** were completed in all their vast array.

Gen 2:1 says God was done creating Earth i.e. our Earth. What about those other planets out there. If at all you find scientific evidence of other planets or stars or heavenly bodies being approximated to at least that were created after Earth, then Yes, there could the possibility of creating Heavenly bodies alone after Earth and after the 7th day.

Other than that, as others have said, he is ever creating Man, every soul from scratch, or babies are being created every single day (here literally).

Not only those things which we could see, but also who knows devils are being created or he created after the 7th day.

So, limiting the word creation to "Heavens and Earth" alone is not a good idea I think.