# Is God still in the process of creation?

Tags: bible

In view of John 5:17;

Joh_5:17  But Jesus answered them, My Father worketh hitherto, and I work.

And the fact that Hubble shows us that new stars, etc. are forming in the Cosmos, it would appear that Creation is an ongoing process.

How does this compare with;

Gen 2:2  And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made.

Comment: The fact that we discover new stars does not mean they only now exist - we just never saw them.

Comment: Never mind; I see what you mean.

Comment: New animals are born too, and new plants spring up.

Comment: Very similar to: [Has God created anything since He rested on the 7th day?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2306/62)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional Christian view on this is that God completed the work of creation in six days (whether you take that literally or metaphorically). However he is still in the business of [*sustaining* his creation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_the_Sustainer). The Catechism of the Catholic Church says in 301:

> With creation, God does not abandon his creatures to themselves. He not only gives them being and existence, but also, and at every moment, upholds and sustains them in being, enables them to act and brings them to their final end. Recognizing this utter dependence with respect to the Creator is a source of wisdom and freedom, of joy and confidence:

In other words, without God's continual work, nothing could continue to exist. It's a separate kind of work from the work of Creation.

As Ryan Frame says, the discovery of new stars does not mean that they were created recently. Also the birth of new stars (or animals, or people for that matter) doesn't imply new creation. God had set in motion at the time of creation the *mechanisms* by which they are created (coalescing matter clouds, sexual reproduction). That was the work of creation. The bringing-to-birth is the work of sustainment.

Additional references to show that this view is not limited to Catholics:

- [Answers in Genesis](http://www.answersingenesis.org/articles/2010/11/18/sustains-us-every-day)
- [Mennonite Articles of Faith](http://www.mennolink.org/doc/cof/art.5.html)
- [Brethren in Christ](http://www.bic-church.org/about/beliefs/god_creation.asp)
- [Anglican Catechism](http://anglicansonline.org/basics/catechism.html)

Comment: Thank you not being a Catholic, but a protestant I am not familiar with any catechisms, or Mennonite tenants. I do have some concerns about being able to see through time as some claim Hubble does, however that is a moot point.

Comment: Feel free to ask questions about the - though it is probably better done at a science site than here.