# Is it possible the Biblical and scientific timelines for the age of the earth could link up?

Tags: history, creation, science, chronology

In many versions of the Bible I have read, in footnotes/endnotes they say the Hebrew term for "day" could also mean "period of time."  So if you took "period of time" to mean oh say, a billion years, pow, the Earth could be seen as 5 to 7 billion years old, which agrees roughly with the scientific community's view.  Then that leaves room for things like evolution, fossil and fossil fuel formation, etc.  Is this something anyone sees as plausible?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a good question but it has already been [asked](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/what-is-old-earth-creationism) and [discussed](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=old+earth). Specifically, you are referring to the [day age theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day-age_creationism), which has [been talked about here before](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=day+age+theory).

Comment: Related (and perhaps even a more direct answer to this question than the one linked as a dupe): http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/642/20

Comment: There is no Biblical basis for the age of the universe. It is just some fancy guess work done by Bible literalist.