# Are there other historical accounts of the tower of Babel?

Tags: babel

Are there any other historical accounts that document what happened during or shortly after the tower of Babel? I was wondering if there are any other accounts from the people's that were dispersed, and how exactly they reacted to the event and built new cultures with their new languages.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question may or may not be answerable here, since it is not universally agreed among Christians even whether it is an account of actual historical events or a figurative and symbolic story. For more on what this site is about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).

Comment: There are other mythological stories of such a tower, but whether they're considered "historical" depends on what you believe about it.

Comment: The 19th-cent scholar, Samuel Davidson made a relevant comment: "As an example of a pure myth may be taken the account of the frustration of the building of Babylon and its tower. The purport of it is to account for the separation of so many peoples, though they all sprung from the same origin."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Christianity.

Answer (score 2):

There are other accounts, which may be considered to tell the same story.  Wikipedia provides [a good list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel#In_other_sources).

Whether any of the accounts (including the Biblical one) are *historical* is entirely another matter. Most historians (outside of a [young-earth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1526/20) tradition) view the myths as (primarily*) fictional, meant to explain the existence of languages to an otherwise naïve audience. Historians take this view because the history of languages is [fairly well understood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_language) and known to predate architecture and human civilization by hundreds of thousands of years.

*This doesn't mean there isn't some element of truth to the stories. I.e. there may have been a tower under construction, which was imbued with additional meaning. But the view is that the story as the origin-of-human-languages is fictional.