# Scientific contradictions in bible

Tags: genesis, textual-discrepancies, science, hebrews

The problems are:-

1. In the [Book of genesis](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=DIV1&byte=1477) it is said that the Universe was created in 6 days. But from the scientific perspective it is impossible. It took billions of years. Also the chronology the bible mentions is inconsistent with modern science. [More information here.](https://youtu.be/NHpQK2UtAio?t=2m12s)
2. In the [Book of Hebrews 1:10-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%201%3A10-12&version=NIV), God says that the Heavens and the Earth will perish.But in the [Book of Psalms 78:69](http://biblehub.com/psalms/78-69.htm) God says the Earth will remain forever. There is a clear contradiction.
3. In [Genesis 1:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%201%3A29&version=KJV) God says that all fruits are safe to eat. But there are many poisonous fruits like wild berries, Datura etc. This is another scientific contradiction.
4. There is a mathematical contradiction [here.](https://youtu.be/NHpQK2UtAio?t=17m58s)

Also there are other scientific contradictions in the total [video.](https://youtu.be/NHpQK2UtAio)

Now my question is, if Bible is the word of God then why does it contain so may contradictions?

My purpose is not to hurt anyone's feelings. I just want to know the truth. If I have hurt someone then I genuinely apologize.

If I have any problems in my question please inform me. Cheers!

Comment: for point 1 see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/648/22319 the bible is not meant to be a scientific text.  For point 4 please don't just have a link, have any point/question in text form

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  This site is dedicated to the study of Christianity and its many denominations.  For example, some denominations believe 6 days was literally 6 days.  Others point to 2 Pet 3:8 and believe it's 6,000 years.  Others point to the same verse and believe it means "six long periods of time."  Without knowing which denomination you're interested in, we cannot answer the question.

Comment: @depperm  i edited the question

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan Please don't do that - you have invalidated the answers that people have already written. Please make a new question instead.

Comment: @curiousdannii Okay I'll do it now

Comment: One question per contradiction would be best please :)

Comment: Every single one of the points you raise has a logical explanation. But nobody is obliged to answer them. Cheers !

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for asking here. Christians believe the Bible does not in fact contain contradictions, and the people who say it does have mostly not studied it closely. The specific issues you raise are resolved as follows:

1. The first few chapters of Genesis are viewed by most Christians as metaphorical language. It tells us important points about creation but not  the scientific mechanism. This belief predates modern science. There is no contradiction with science. Alternatively some Christians believe the story is literally true  but modern science is wrong.
2. The Psalms are poetry. They are not intended to convey scientific fact. You might however like to remember that while the Earth will pass away it will be replaced by another Earth, and so there will in fact be an Earth for all eternity.
3. Genesis 1 does not say that all fruit are good to eat, only that all fruit in the Garden was good to eat at that time. Many also believe that the Earth changed after the Fall of Man, and that fruit maybe became harmful after that.

Comment: +1 for "all fruit in the garden."  Many don't realize that the garden was inside Eden, not Eden itself.  We're not told what the nature of the world was outside the Garden (it wasn't important to the lesson).

Comment: @ DJClayworth I have edited the question. Please answer the answer the  new points., Thanks!

Comment: If you have new points, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The Bible does not explicitly contradict science, but when looking at the Bible as a textbook it only appears to contradict.  The general statement that science and the Bible contradict each other is equivalent to saying that Lee Child's books about Jack Reacher (or other novels or other styles of books like cookbooks) contradict science.  Those books are novels and for a different purpose, though they have some facts in them they are not a supplement or replacement for science.  I am not saying that the Bible is a novel or fiction, but the point is that it's a different purpose.
If the Bible is a textbook of sorts, then it's a textbook about faith.

The passages quoted are also out of context.  When looking at a single sentence in a story, it is easy to take it away from the bigger meaning of that sentence and the story.

Regarding each item...
1.  The story of Genesis is a story of creation not from a science perspective, but of faith and reason.  It answers the question 'why' nit 'how'.  We see evidence in this as there are two stories of creation in the Bible, plus the one story doesn't have the sky created until the second day (or the heavens and Earth by the end of the first day), so if there was no day/night right away how could one measure what a full day was?  The point of this story is different than the cliff notes if "a brief history of time".  The author makes many points and one thing he uses is a literary device.  God makes Earth, it's good, sky good, animals good, water good...until he made humans it was VERY GOOD.  The point is we are more than animals or water or sky and this sets up for the rest of the story.

2. The author starts the psalm by saying it's a parable, a story to teach.  This is doesn't contradict anything as it's stated it's supposed to be a simile and metaphor and more literary devices.  Even the one line out of context makes this reference.  Additionally, is is not that the earth will live forever or never be destroyed, rather it was founded or established forever which is very different.  I am married, and will be forever, though I may die, I cannot unmarry, I will forever be bonded to my wife, "till death do us part", but at that point I am still technically married as that can't be undone then.
   The quote from Hebrews is again out of context and part of a larger story and used as a simile and metaphor, just as the author states in the first line.  Additionally, the passage states both perish and founded forever for the earth, but those are not opposed to each other.
3. Again context and not contradicting at all.  The author states in the story that it is meant in the garden of Eden.  It is also not contradicting that all as it is revealed that the tree Adam and Eve shouldn't eat from they were told they would die if they ate from it, although that sounds poisonous in some way, they don't die at all when the do eat of it.  Again, more story to show certain points.
4. The video doesn't have sound math or arguments on either side.  I am not sure where to begin with it, its not worth to correct every word and surmise what is  intended by either side.

The Bible is a story about the map to a great treasure.  Science is explaining what that treasure is and how the map was made and the cyphers used to reveal the mystery to us.

"It is absurd for the Evolutionist to complain that it is unthinkable for an admittedly unthinkable God to make everything out of nothing, and then pretend that it is more thinkable that nothing should turn itself into everything.”

"The riddles of God are more satisfying than the solutions of man.”

“Let your religion be less of a theory and more of a love affair.”

-GK Chesterton