# Where do Dinousaurs fit in the bible?

Tags: archaeology

We have archaeological evidence that dinosaurs existed and walked upon the earth once upon a time in the history of the earth. Their fossils are dated some million years back. Where do these creatures fit in ?

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9918/23657.

Comment: Where do they fit?  Just inside the back cover, but you need a really big Family Bible or Pulpit Bible.

Comment: Just because the Bible doesn't mention something doesn't mean that its Author had nothing to do with it.