# What is the specific meaning of "die" in Genesis 2?

Tags: genesis, exegesis

[Genesis 2:16-17 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202:16-17&version=NIV):

> <sup>16</sup>And the LORD God commanded the man, “You are free to eat from any tree in the garden; <sup>17</sup>but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will certainly die.”

KJV says:

> for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.

It seems clear that Adam and Eve did not die on the *day* they ate from the tree. And even without the word "day" there, it seems they didn't die "when" they ate from the tree, either, but many many years later.

What gives?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an unscoped exegesis question without and, without any theological framework to answer from, a "truth" question. It could be re-asked as-is on [hermeneutics.se] or modified to be an overview question that forces answers to note what options are out there rather than argue for the truth of one of them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The death promised and that Adam experienced the moment he chose to sin was not a ceasing to exist or a physical stopping to breathe, it was a separation: a rending apart of two things that were once closely joined. On the day that Adam ate the fruit, he died<sup>1</sup>. He was separated from God. The fellowship between them was broken.

The reverse of this death happens when we are 'born again'. The fellowship is restored, and we are born into *new life* -- the power of the cross is that it reverses death!

The alternative, for those who are not born again into a new life, is that they will experience a 'second death'. This is partly a contrast between physical and spiritual death. It happens sequentially after physical death (making it second) but is also the point at which spiritual separation  becomes permanent (having died once with Adam, they will be judged to permanent death). The reverse is true for believers: we will be raised into life even though we die.

This is an important doctrine to understand in light of many popular culture understandings of death as some kind of annihilation or ceasing to exist. Never in Scripture do we find an indications that any humans well cease to exist, but we do find lots of information about the change in our relationship before God.

This understanding of death as a separation or rending apart of two things once joined is also the sense of 'death' that [Romans](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Romans%208:13) and [1st Peter](http://www.esvbible.org/search/1%20Peter%202:24) use when they speak of believers being *dead to sin*. We are no longer bound to it as a slave is to his master. Believers relationship with sin has been severed and we have been cleaved to a new master.

When we physically die, our spirits are separated from the bodies that we have been one with<sup>2</sup>. Our bodies don't cease to exist nor do our spirits, but they part ways<sup>3</sup>. Our bodies then decay and return to dust, but even the material in this world doesn't cease to exist. Our spirits meanwhile continue, either in eternal life (unity with Christ) or eternal death (separation from Him).

1. > **[Genesis 2:17](http://www.esvbible.org/search/gen+2%3A17/)** (ESV)
   >   but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat1 of it you shall surely die.”
2. > **[Genesis 35:18](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Genesis%2035:18)** (ESV)
   >   And as her soul was departing (for she was dying), she called his name Ben-oni; but his father called him Benjamin.
   >   **[James 2:26](http://www.esvbible.org/search/James%202:26)** (ESV)
   >   For as the body apart from the spirit is dead, so also faith apart from works is dead.
3. > **[Ecclesiastes 12:7](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Ecclesiastes%2012:7)** (ESV)
   >   and the dust returns to the earth as it was, and the spirit returns to God who gave it.

Comment: Sadly it seems the year I was born was the year somebody forwarded a different idea about what death means. Here is [an article for further reading](http://www.christiancourier.com/articles/710-the-second-death-separation-or-annihilation). Also here are [lots more verses and some charts](http://www.bible.ca/d-death=separation.htm).

Comment: What about Gen 3:22? after Adam and Eve sinned "the LORD God said, 'The man has now become like one of us, knowing good and evil. He must not be allowed to reach out his hand and take also from the tree of life and eat, and live forever.'" That sure sounds like physically living forever.

Comment: @Caleb You mention separation from God in eternity for those who do not believe.  Do you believe in "eternal damnation" as more than just separation, but suffering, as in living in pain a lake of fire or whatnot?

Comment: Well thought answer

Answer (score 7):

That is talking about physical death because when Adam disobeyed, God in his mercy had to cut him off from the tree of life so he would not live forever in his sin [Genesis 3:22-24 (KJV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203:22-24&version=KJV).

> <sup>22</sup>And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever:
>
> <sup>23</sup>Therefore the LORD God sent him forth from the garden of Eden, to till the ground from whence he was taken. <sup>24</sup>So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of life.

God DID in fact cut him off from the tree of life that day, so Adam did start to die.

Comment: This raises the question, which has also been asked, [what is the tree of life](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/what-is-the-significance-of-the-tree-of-life-in-the-garden-of-eden)?

Comment: I find the argument "they began to die" difficult to swallow... if that's what the Bible meant, surely it would have said that, no?  Also in light of other uses of the term 'die' and 'death', it seems that it always means something more immediate (and not always physical) in the Bible.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a more superficial answer might be that if one day for God is 1,000 years for man, and Adam lived to be 930 years old ([Genesis 5:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205:5&version=KJV)), then Adam really did die on the same "day".

**[2 Peter 3:8 (KJV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%203:8&version=KJV)**

> But, beloved, be not ignorant of this one thing, that one day is with the Lord as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day.

Also **[Psalms 90:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalms%2090:4&version=KJV)**

> For a thousand years in thy sight are but as yesterday when it is past, and as a watch in the night.

Comment: Exactly. Provided Adam was also immortal and eternal when God told him not to eat. I believe that Adam was not bounded by time before the fall and hence a day and a thousand years was same to Adam as well. Remember, Adam was created in the image of God.

Answer (score 0):

According to Romans 6:23 "the wages of sin is death" (KJV) so death is the wages of sin and all that involves. For instance,

- Temporal life on earth because the physical death appears like something new.
- Total depravity or corrupted nature of men slaved to sin. With the new physical death, the men could kill each others and themselves.
- Sickness.
- Aging.
- Unhollyness and separation from God.
- All of this and much more...

Would help to know what Christ came to do, because consist in the reverse or the restitution of the falled nature.

**EDIT**: Obs: I ommited the connection of the word "death" in that verse of Romans with the word "die" of the verse of Genesis because that is obvious for every christian and we are in a christianity forum.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a doubling in this phrase that is not uncommon in Hebrew syntax and has been translated various ways](http://www.accuracyingenesis.com/die.html) like, "you will surely die."

I would like to focus on "in the day that you eat of it" and suggest that a proper understanding of what God says is best gained by looking at the events following their disobedience.

Note how, prior to Adam and eve's disobedience, they could eat of any fruit of any tree in the garden.  The only one they could not eat of was the tree of the knowledge of good and evil. So **they could have eaten any time from the tree of life and thus lived forever**.

> 15    Then the LORD God took the man and put him in the garden of Eden to tend and keep it.
>   16  And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, "Of every tree of the garden you may freely eat;

But instead they chose to eat of the fruit from the tree God forbade:

> 17    but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not
>   eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die."

cf.

> So when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree desirable to make one wise, she took of its fruit and ate. She also gave to her husband with her, and he ate.

Now notice **right after** God finishes reproving Adam, eve, and the serpent, he clothes them, and **(seemingly in that very day), He sets a guard so they no longer could eat and live forever**.  Thus, they will die.

> Genesis 3:24 So He drove out the man; and He placed cherubim at the east of the garden of Eden, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to guard the way to the tree of life.

So, rather than reading t as "in the day you eat of it you will die that day," we understand by the unfolding of its fulfillment: in the day you eat of it you will no longer have access to the tree of life. Thus you will surely die.

Answer (score 0):

See https://answersingenesis.org/death-before-sin/genesis-2-17-you-shall-surely-die/

They say that an acceptable translation of the phrase is "dying you shall die", and back it up by showing an identical construction found in Numbers 7:10–84, informing the people that that generation would die in the desert without reaching the promised land. The whole generation did not die on the same day - it was spread out over time.

Thus the phrase means that a process of dying would immediately begin, and its sure result would be an ultimate death.

Answer (score -1):

Die  as  described  in  Genesis 3;19:

In  the  sweat  of  thy  face  shalt  thou  eat  bread,  till  thou  return  unto  the  ground:  for  out  of  it  wast  thou  taken:  for  dust  thou  art  and  unto  dust  shalt  thou  return.

Ecclesiastes 9;5

For  the  living  know  that  they  shall  die,  but  the  dead  know  not  any  thing;  neither  have  they  any  more  a  reward;  for  the  memory  of  them  is  forgotten.

Adam  and  Eve  did  not  die  physically that  day,  a   substitute  was  offered,  Jesus  Christ.

Genesis 3;21

Unto  Adam  also  and  to  his  wife  did  the  LORD  God  make  coats  of  skins,  and  clothed  them.

However,  Adam   and  Eve  did  die  spiritually,  that  day.

Isaiah  59;2

But  your  iniquities  have  seperated  between  you  and  your  God,  and  your  sins  have  hid  his  face  from  you,  that he  will  not  hear.

Later,  Adam  and  Eve  physically  died.  Eves  death  is  not  recorded.

Genesis 5;5

And  all the days  that Adam lived  were  nine  hundred  and  thirty  years:  and  he  died.

Note;  When  Adam  was  driven  out  of  the  garden,  they  no  longer  had  access  to  the  tree  of  life  that  had  sustained  them  and  immortality.  They  would  now  physically  die.  Mans  life  force  has  always  existed  outside  himself.  We  are  not  immortal  in  any  fashion.

2  Timothy  1;10    But  is  now  made  manifest  by  the  appearing  of  our  Saviour  Jesus  Christ,  who  hath  abolished  death,  and  hath  brought  life  and  immorality  to  light  through  the  gospels: