# Matthew 26:24, is God Omnibenevolent?

Tags: nature-of-god, gospel-of-matthew, omnibenevolence

I'm really interested about Matthew 26:24 in which Jesus said that

> The Son of Man will go just as it is written about him. But woe to that man who betrays the Son of Man! It would be better for him if he had not been born."

Since this verse is talking about the betrayal of Judas, it seems that Jesus is affirming the eternal fate that awaits Judas by saying that it is better if Judas is had not been born.

Why is God who is Omnibenevolent knows that Judas will be better of if he had not been born **let** Judas to be born?

or

How can we say that God is Omnibenevolent if He made a decision (creating Judas) in which He fully knows that His decision will made one of His creation fate much-much worse in the end?

PS: This question is for all of you although I have special interest for answer from **christian universalism** point of view, hope u guys can chip in :) Thanks!

Comment: This is  rephrasing of [How can a Wholly Good God Deliberately Create Evil?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/how-can-a-wholly-good-god-deliberately-create-evil) aka [the Logical Problem of Evil](http://carm.org/god-and-evil-a-philosophical-contradiction), which has been asked and addressed here ***many*** times already.

Comment: Several hits on the subject. Hopefully these will be useful: [site search for 'problem of evil'](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=problem+of+evil)

Comment: @DavidStratton yes it is, however I'm interested in answer that can relate to the Matthew 26:24 if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking why God allows people to sin, without taking their lives beforehand, or even allowing them to live at all. Or how about "Why does God create people that will end up in hell?", because it would be better for anyone to not be born than to turn from their creator.

God created us and gave us free will, knowing we would turn to our own ways. He perfectly chose Adam and Eve to represent you and I. He also knew that some would repent and yearn for Him. Now I do not recall if it's mentioned that Adam (or Eve) find redemption, but if not and God had not allowed them to live long enough to sin, then mankind would not exist. It would be wrong for God to take every man's life that would not be saved through faith and repentance before they had sinned. God offers salvation to every sinful man ([Matt 7:7-8)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matt.%207:7-8&version=NIV&utm_expid=13466113-5&utm_referrer=http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%252026:20-30&version=NIV). If all of these people had died so soon, or before they were even born, then how many souls would not even come to be? How many would not even be offered life and salvation?

Obviously if Judas ends up in hell, then it would be better if he had died before he sinned. I think Jesus is giving us a metaphor or simile in plain terms of the pain and suffering he would endure from his conviction for betrayal to his suicide, or perhaps in hell, or both.

Answer (score 0):

> Heb 6:18  That by two immutable things, in which it was impossible for God to lie, we might have a strong consolation, who have fled for refuge to lay hold upon the hope set before us:
>
> 2Ti 2:13  If we believe not, yet he abideth faithful: he cannot deny himself.
>
> Tit 1:2  In hope of eternal life, which God, that cannot lie, promised before the world began;
>
> Psalm 5:4 Holman For You are not a God who delights in wickedness; evil cannot dwell with You.

I'm not a universalist. I'm Word of Faith and this is our position I understand it. God is Omnibenevolent but he is not Omnipotent by the common definition of Omnipotent. There are a set of thing categorized as evil which he cannot do. God allows many things but He does not cause everything. God did not force Judas to be born. His parents caused Judas' birth. God gave Judas' body form and a human spirit but he gives everybody form and spirit. It would be evil for whatever reason for God to deny this basic equal treatment to all those created from Adam. (It is possible for the devil to interfere with the work of God and a body to be born defected or otherwise afflicted. The devil truly is evil.) Judas was born tabula rasa he had the ability to make a good life to be a normal member of the 12 but he was corrupted by his own covetousness and the devil.

Answer (score -1):

God created man in His own image - created to live a godlike life - free to reason and act. Man was was not created to be a robot. After the fall of man, God's redemption plans were put to use with the sole intent of giving back to man the godlike inheritance that was lost in the garden of Eden. The only way to regain that inheritance is to follow Jesus - who is the way, the truth and the life.

God has set in motion all things, with perfection. He rarely interferes with His perfect creation except when those who have chosen to follow His redemption plan call on Him to intervene.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: This answer would be much better if it stated whose beliefs it was describing, because 1) personal opinions are not allowed on this site, and 2) believe it or not, what you've described is not universally accepted by Christians. The answer would also be improved if it interacted with Matthew 26:24, as requested by the questioner.

Answer (score -2):

God is omnibenevolent in such a way that He is perfectly good (Deut.32:4).He did not creat evil to duel within us but we caused it,God did not creat Judas to end up in hell, Jesus has to die to save the world,but because of the selfish and the love of money life in Judas he betrayed His master.he will by all means end up in hell due to the life that he was living because the word of God let us know that people living such will not enter the Kingdom of God(Galat.5:19-21). God is not injustice. I think Judas had the chance to change his ending by asking for forgiveness but rather committed suicide making it worse(Prov.28:13)(Isaiah 1:18). He was with Jesus all the time he heard Jesus saying that it will be better if person had not been born but due to his love for money which is the root of all evil he still went ahead in betraying Jesus. The Bible says blaspheming against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven but did not say anything about betraying so he could have asked for forgiveness. Jesus is not only talking to Judas but all of us,betrayers or traitors will end up in hell so we should change.God loved Judas and created him to live but he chose his on way(John 3:16) .not only Judas but everyone who is a traitor and betrayer should turn to God for HE will freely forgive.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. Remember that "I believe it means..." isn't an acceptable answer, since this site isn't about personal interpretation.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)