# Does Bible say that God created insects?

Tags: creation

Does Bible say that God created insects? Does "creeping things" in Genesis imply insects, too?

Comment: I'd suggest making this specific to [Gen 1:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen%201%3A24&version=WLC;ESV) (*remeś*) and moving it to [Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) (....or not, pending [Which “no-tradition-specified” exegesis questions should be closed?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6075/which-no-tradition-specified-exegesis-questions-should-be-closed)). (You may find the "swarmers"  (*šereṣ*) of interest as well, though that's not evident from Gen. 1.)

Comment: If not Genesis, John 1:3

Comment: This might be a good question for  Hermeneutics.SE, but is probably out of scope here, as it we do not answer questions about the truth of the Bible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any verse that specifically mentions insects, but at the beginning of John it says 'All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.'. JNDs translation puts it 'All things
received being through him, and without him not one [thing] received being which has received being.' So he must have created the insects...

Some other food for thought.....

Amos 7 'Thus hath the Lord GOD shewed unto me; and, behold, he formed grasshoppers in the beginning of the shooting up of the latter growth;'(be sure to get the context)

Psalm 105 'He spoke, and there came dog-ﬂies, [and] gnats in all their borders....He spoke, and the locust came, and the cankerworm, even without number;'

Psalm 50 'I know all the fowl of the mountains, and the
roaming creatures of the field are mine:'

Comment: Thanks for all these links. In fact, they are the answer to my question. But... as far as "all things were made by Him", would you then say that sin was also created by God?!

Comment: Welcome Joel! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @jaguar The question of where sin comes from is widely debated.  You can start with this question: [How can a Wholly Good God Deliberately Create Evil?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/8743/21576)  If you'd like to ask a separate question about it, be sure to specify *which tradition's view you want*.

Comment: @jaguar, some Christian theologies hold that sin is not a substance in and of itself, but is rather the state of man when he is separated from God.  In ancient Greek, the word (verb form ἁμαρτάνω, noun ἁμαρτία) was used to convey a meaning of "missing a mark" or "missing a target" (e.g. it is found in the Iliad to describe an archer missing someone with his arrow).    Under such understanding, sinning is not an act of commission, but fundamentally an act of omission ...

Comment: ... This is also implied in the verb prefix "a".  In English words of Greek origin it usually denotes an absence of something:  e.g. "a-political", "a-theist". [In Greek the word is "hamartia", which begins with an acceted "a"- ἁ].

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any specific exegetical basis, but yes, "creeping things" (in Genesis 1:24 and elsewhere) has usually been understood to include both reptiles and insects (or all arthropods more generally).