# Why didn't Adam and Eve die when they ate the fruit?

Tags: original-sin, eden

God gave Adam and Eve the following command, followed by a cause

> Genesis 2:17-  But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou
>   shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou
>   shalt surely die.  KJV

Even so, they ate and still lived a long life, not dying in the same day

> Genesis 5:5-  And all the days that Adam lived were nine hundred and
>   thirty years: and he died.  KJV

Is it as simple as "day" referring to a different period of time than it refers to today?

Comment: This is the question you're looking for [What is the specific meaning of “die” in Genesis 2?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/what-is-the-specific-meaning-of-die-in-genesis-2)