# When was the first man created?

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, history, adam-and-eve

As with reference to the Genesis when did the God create man? And also the difference between two verses below

> Genesis 1:27 So God created mankind in his own image,
>          in the image of God he created them;
>          male and female **he created them**.
>
> Genesis 2:7 Then the Lord God **formed a man[c] from the dust of the ground** and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man
>   became a  living being.

Also wanted to know why specifically two times it has been mentioned two times that god created male female in his image and then formed man from the dust.

Comment: Covers the same ground as [Controversy regarding the birth of man](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16411/controversy-regarding-the-birth-of-man)

Comment: its an different kinda question and doesnt make any sense to my question

Comment: Isaac Newton estimated that the biblical date of creation was circa 4000 BC. By modern scholarship, that would be ludicrous; however, Newton lived in the dawn of the modern world. In his era, his critical thinking, academic rigor, and effort were what mattered and made progress in science.

Comment: Look at the answers on that question.  Not mine, necessarily. The answer given by @pterandon shows the different views on Creationism.  His answer covers the ground you're asking about. Short version: There's not agreement.  There are many views on this.  he covers the main three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In attempting to bring clarity, let's look at these scriptures as complimentary.

"Created," as stated in 1:27 is the overarching term stating that God did make man.

> Genesis 1:27 So God *created* mankind in his own image, in the image of God he created them; male and female he created them.

The word "formed" in 2:7 is a statement if how God created man.

> Genesis 2:7 Then the Lord God *formed* a man[c] from the dust of the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living being.

Comment: Interesting analogy, "created vs. formed". So, its possible God created male and female but did not breath in the Holy Spirit like in the case of Eve, but in the case of Adam, the bible used the word "formed" to distinguished Adam had received the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis One is the introductory paragraph. Genesis 2 goes into the specific detail on the creation of man in Genesis 1.

Genesis 5:1-2 ties the two passages together, wording it both ways, demonstrating Genesis 1 and 2 are speaking of the same event.